# What does it mean that Monitor is unbound and can be called directly from any context?

Tags: c#, multithreading, monitor

There is a sentence in [Monitor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.monitor.aspx) description about its features, that states:

> It is unbound, which means it can be called directly from any context

Does anyone might explain what means *context* here and give an example?

Comment: I'm not sure I'd do a good job trying to explain it, but you might try reading the help for `ContextBoundObject` and then following links from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply put. Monitor's methods can be invoked regardless of working thread, application and object state, in all syntacticly valid places in the code.